# Binding "onkeypress" event to a jQuery Easy UI Datagrid Editor type "text"?

Tags: datagrid, editor, jquery-easyui, onkeypress

Is it possible to bind a "onkeypress" event to a jQuery Easy UI Datagrid Editor type "text"?
or "onkeyup" and "onkeydown".

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following demo,

http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid15.php

Comment: thank you,I also read that URL before I post this question, in the sample it says "someEditor.target.bind('change',function(){});", however what I want is keypress event, that mean the keypress event must be send to callback function. I wrote "someEditor.target.bind('change',function(event){});" and "someEditor.target.bind('keypress',function(event){});" and "someEditor.target.bind('onkeypress',function(event){});" and "someEditor.target.bind('onkeyup',function(event){});" but none of them fired.

Answer (score 0):

You should register your event on datagrid's `onLoadSuccess` event, like this:

```
onLoadSuccess:function() {
  $(".onetextbox").keydown(function () {
    // ...
  });
}
```